# How can I solve the "Cookie csrftoken will be soon rejected because it has the sameSite attribute set to none" warning on my Django 2.0 application?

Tags: django, csrf

I am using version 2.0 and I just noticed on my firefox developer tools this message:

`Cookie “csrftoken” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value.`

It seems that django 2.0 does not store `SameSite` attribute along with this cookie.

(for example something like this: `Set-Cookie: CookieName=CookieValue; SameSite=Lax;`)

Is there a workaround for this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with an old Django 1.8 system, but simply updating the `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` value to `True` in my `settings.py` file resolved the warning for me.

Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure) for more info.